# Is it possible to customise Dynamics 365? Web Design?

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

Is it possible to edit Dynamics 365 in a way to change how certain entities look when they are opened. I don't mean forms, apps or views. I want to be able to change how the accounts entity looks, such as; a smaller view box, the location of the search bar and additional helpful information from other entities.

I simple would like to know if this is possible to achieve with Dynamics 365?

I can supply more info of what I would like to do if it helps to answer my question.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

UI wise you can control the following:

- Form layout, i.e. what fields appear and where.
- You can include data from related entities (associated record grids, and quick view forms).
- Colours, using branding.
- Size of text boxes.

You can't change:

- The location of the search bar.

Not sure what a "a smaller view box" would be, but you might be able to achieve something similar by changing the form layout.